# Remove item from object by key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux

So I created React Todo App with an Object as a Todo List. Removing an item by key works with *delete*, but brings me back boolean instead of Object with the rest of the items.

```
  deleteTodo = (id) => {
const { todos } = this.state;
this.setState({
  todos: delete todos[id],
});
```

I get this in console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `todos` of type `boolean` supplied to `TodoList`, expected an object.
```

Comment: Try to `delete todos[id];` first and then do a `setState`

Answer (score 8):

You should use **immutable operations** when using Redux. You should not change your state directly.

For that, you can use **destructuring** to exclude your todo from the todos, if your todos are in an object:

```
const { todos } = this.state;
const { [id]: _, ...newTodos } = todos;
this.setState({
    todos: newTodos
});
```

If the todos are in a list and since you cannot destructure an item by index from an array, **use the `slice` method**, which doesn't modify the array, but returns a modified copy:

```
const { todos } = this.state;
this.setState({
    todos: [...todos.slice(0, id), ...todos.slice(id + 1)];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to firstly copy your state to an array so you have a clone of it.

Then you remove the unwanted id from your new array.

```
var newTodoArray = this.state;

newTodoArray.remove(id);

    this.setState({
      todos: newTodoArray,
   });
```

Something like the above.